# PICKADATE.JS With Angular.js ng-click is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

**HTML :**

```
<a class="book3" ng-click="te($event);"><span>Book</span></a>
```

**JS:**

```
 $scope.te =  function($event) {
             alert("");
        var inputRec = $event.target;
        $event.target.pickadate();

        }
```

I want to add the pickadate element to the HTML element. But unable to do . I dont want to create directives cause its not working as intended.

I did it in jquery by

```
$(".book3").on("click",function(){
this.pickadate();
})
```

But now i want it to do in angular way.

Here is the link of Pickadate http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/

Comment: Are you sure that you have set up your controller correctly? Is the function not firing at all or rather malfunctioning? What is not "working as intended" when it comes to directives?

Comment: The alert is showup . But the pickadate is not adding to the dom element

Comment: I would wrap that `<a>` element in a directive, then work with the actual element reference instead of `$event.target`. I don't even know if this is possible the way you are trying. DOM manipulation should always be handled through directives.